# ANTRL4 is parsing incorrectly

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

While learning ANTRL4 I tried to parse very basic pattern, which can have one **or more digits**.

**Abc.g4**

```
grammar Abc;

@header {
    package antlr4;
}

fragment DIGIT : [0-9]+;

log : DIGIT;
```

**Main method**

```
public class OwnParser extends AbcBaseListener
{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String javaClassContent = "9";
        AbcLexer abcLexer = new AbcLexer(CharStreams.fromString(javaClassContent));

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(abcLexer);
        AbcParser parser = new AbcParser(tokens);

         ParseTree tree = parser.log();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        OwnParser listener= new OwnParser();

        walker.walk(listener, tree);
    }
}
```

But when I execute this, it says:

> line 1:0 token recognition error at: '9'
>
> line 1:1 missing DIGIT at ''
>
> rule entered: <missing DIGIT>

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

You get an error on the input `9` because you didn't define any lexer rule that matches `9`. In fact, you didn't define any lexer rules at all. Note that you defined `DIGIT` as a fragment only and fragments don't produce tokens.

You should also have gotten a warning "implicit definition of token DIGIT in parser" in your grammar.

If you remove the `fragment` keyword from the definition of `DIGIT`, both of those problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks sepp2k. Can you please help me understand difference between fragment and rule ?

Comment: @pratik When processing input, the lexer goes through all the lexer rules to see which match the input. It then selects the one that produces the longest match and then generates a token with the corresponding token type. It does not look at fragments for this, only at lexer rules. Fragments only exist to be called by lexer rules. They do not have any effect by themselves.